# What answer to accept?

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer, answer-quality

There are so many good answers to my questions that it's sometimes hard to decide what answer to designate as accepted. I really feel that more than one is "accepted."

What should one do in this case? Pick one randomly or just leave no answer marked as accepted?

Comment: Is it irony that this question has 12 answers but none accepted?

Comment: Yes. Ok, I'll pick one.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The best answer.

If there are several equally good answers, go with the one posted first.

Don't be afraid to switch your accepted answer to someone else if a better answer gets added later.

Comment: +1 for pointing this out. I never realized we can do this.

Answer (score 11):

Pick the earliest correct answer.

Comment: Doesn't this kind of make the community voting for answers redundant?

Comment: It's all subjective.

Comment: @Sam Menard Right, lol!

Comment: Just for the record - I would only look at time if they are at the same level - "best" beats "earliest" by a long margin. If you've already *got* an accepted answer, I would leave a comment on the ex-accepted answer, saying why.

Answer (score 6):

Earliest of the best answers; vote the others up.

Answer (score 4):

Well I guess this comes down to the person's own algorithm for preference.

You could rate the correct answers by:

1. Time to supply answer
2. User's current rating (lowest first, to reward them! ;) )
3. Grammar
4. Clarity and depth of answer (i.e., do they talk about caveats to a solution as well as the solution)

Comment: I don't agree with "2", the other attributes are more important for me

Answer (score 3):

Pick one that seems most correct, and if there are two that are the same correctness, pick the one that came in first.  Also, if you create a question, you should vote up anybody who you found had a good answer.

Answer (score 2):

Surely in many cases you're going to want to accept the correct answer that the "community" has voted for, so taking into account the one with the most votes is something that should be considered.

That is kind of what the voting is for anyway, not just for helping people get medals.

Answer (score 1):

Gather all of the information in each comment up, add it as a single comment yourself, and accept that comment.  It's not about rewarding people, it's about putting the best answer at the top.

Comment: I don't think you can accept your own answer?

Answer (score 1):

The most complete, accurate and sincere answer. For me, it doesn't matter if it comes earlier or later.

Answer (score 0):

Just pick the best one using any criteria you might think of - people like to be appreciated and an 'accepted' answer is definitely a token of appreciation.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since it is collaborative you could edit your entry to combine the best of all the answers given!

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest making your questions more specific such that there is only one correct answer. The first one to provide it gets the bump.

Answer (score 0):

Take your time.  There's no rush.  After you've selected your answer you can still show your support for other answers by voting up/adding comments.