# You've selected an answer, but a better one comes along. What to do?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, best-practices

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What answer to accept?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28276/what-answer-to-accept)

This questions the intensions of SO. What if someone comes up with a great, insightful answer for your question and you select it as the best answer, and then someone builds upon that a little bit. The second answer is the "best" answer, but the hard work was done by prior poster. Should one select the most complete answer or the one of which had the most work into it?

Comment: Your question is splintered. Just choose the best one that solves your problem.

Comment: Same ground: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28276/what-answer-to-accept

Comment: Upvote them both, leave comments if necessary, but still accept the "best" one.

Answer (score 1):

One should select the best answer.

If a user just copy&pasted the old one and added little (but in your opinion important) content you could incorporate it in the old accepted answer if you have enough rep, or ask a mod to do it otherwise. <s>In this case you could also ask a mod to delete the other answer, which becomes redundant.</s>

Comment: We're unlikely to delete an answer on that basis, but your other suggestions are good ones.

Comment: @Bill: ok, stroke that part out